# Telerik radcaptcha - change generate new image message

Tags: asp.net, telerik, captcha

I am using the Telerik Radcaptcha control with my asp.net application. It works I want however there is a small issue. I have the EnableRefreshImage property set to true, which creates a link that has the text "Generate new Image", when clicked the captcha image changes, this is fine for English versions of the page but I want a different message for other languages. I've looked at the documentation for this control and am not seeing where you can set the text for the new image link. Could anyone tell me how this is done?

For reference here is the markup for the control:

```
<telerik:RadCaptcha ID="fb_Captcha" runat="server" CaptchaTextBoxLabel=""
ProtectionMode="Captcha" CaptchaImage-Height="35" CaptchaImage-Width="100" CaptchaImage-TextLength="5"
ErrorMessage="The code you entered is not valid"  Text="None"  EnableRefreshImage="true" />
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The text for the Refresh link button is changed through the CaptchaLinkButtonText Attribute.

```
<telerik:RadCaptcha ID="fb_Captcha" runat="server" CaptchaTextBoxLabel=""
ProtectionMode="Captcha" CaptchaImage-Height="35" CaptchaImage-Width="100" CaptchaImage-TextLength="5"
ErrorMessage="The code you entered is not valid"  Text="None"  EnableRefreshImage="true" CaptchaLinkButtonText="Refresh" />
```

You can also change the text to an image using the css:

```
.rcRefreshImage
{
    padding: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('../Images/RefreshButton.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik maintains its own forums and I am sure they can cover how to set up globalization and localization with radCaptcha. I would post for an answer.